# IIS - https:// works while http://host:443 doesn't

Tags: iis, ssl, http, https, html

This is my site:

```
http://scyk.pl
```

When you go

```
https://scyk.pl
```

Everything is ok, but when you go

```
http://scyk.pl:443
```

Connection is timing out. I am running IIS7, today I configured ssl, and I don't know why :443 version is not working. Any help?

Comment: You need to go to https://scyk.pl:443  with https. https is different than http Not sure if this is spam.

Comment: Well, more importantly, why do you want the port explicitly in the url?

Comment: But I want it to be like HTTP://scyk.pl:443 and behave like it was HTTPS

Comment: @HopelessN00b: I have asp mvc app running, and for some reason it is trying to use http://scyk.pl:443 as ssl version.

Answer (score 2):

The third URL you're using is just plain wrong; it tells to your web browser to access `scyk.pl` on port 443 using the `HTTP` protocol, but since the website listening on that port is actually using the `HTTPS` protocol, the connection fails. This is exactly the expected behaviour.

Comment: And is there anything I can do about it? I mean, when server sees http://scyk.pl:443, it redirects it to https:// ? Is this possible?

Comment: The "http" or "https" part in the URL will force your web browser to use one protocol or the other; there's nothing the *web server* can do if the client is using the wrong protocol to access a web site.